# Create a folder structure based on information from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, file, data-science

I have this dataframe train_info with 423 different artists and filenames corresponding to images of paintings.

```py
    artist             filename
0   Hiroshige          53180.jpg
1   Ivan Aivazovsky    99442.jpg
2   Hiroshige          23508.jpg
3   Hieronymus Bosch   82352.jpg
4   Hiroshige          27254.jpg
... ... ... ... ...
128069  Frans Snyders   14264images161.jpg
128070  Frans Snyders   14260images158.jpg
128071  Frans Snyders   14274images170.jpg
128072  Frans Snyders   14355images90.jpg
128073  Frans Snyders   14270images167.jpg
```

Then i have a folder - Paintings - containing all these images.

What i want to do is create another folder - train - with sub-folders for each artist and each sub-folder should contain all the images corresponding to each artist.

Like this:

```py
-train
    -Hiroshige
         -53180.jpg
         -23508.jpg
         -27254.jpg
         ...
    -Ivan Aivazovsky
         -99442.jpg
         ...
    -Frans Snyders
         -14264images161.jpg
         -14260images158.jpg
         -14274images170.jpg
         -14355images90.jpg
         -14270images167.jpg
         ...
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: _I have no idea how to solve this._ Can you break down the problem at all?

Comment: Yes i could have written some pseudo code. But i did not think that would be at all helpful for anyone answering.

Comment: It would have probably been helpful to both us and you.

Comment: Ok, i will do that next time (since i already have got an answer to this question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy, no-sweat way, is to use explicit looping:

```
import os
import shutil

srcdir = 'Paintings'
dstdir = 'train'

for name, s in df.groupby('artist')['filename']:
    artistdir = os.path.join(dstdir, name)
    print(f'copying {s.shape[0]} images from {srcdir} to {artistdir}')
    os.makedirs(artistdir, exist_ok=True)
    for filename in s:
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(srcdir, name), os.path.join(artistdir, name))
```

Output:

```
copying 1 images from Paintings to train/Hieronymus Bosch
copying 3 images from Paintings to train/Hiroshige
copying 1 images from Paintings to train/Ivan Aivazovsky
...
```

There are faster ways (in terms of pandas operations), but here the `copy` itself dwarfs that time.